# Desinstalar NPM de Windows

Tags: nodejs, windows, npm, nvm

Tengo un problema, deseo desinstalar NVM de windows porque, no me deja ejecutar aplicaciones angular, alguien sabe como lo desinstalo

Comment: Cristian, te doy la bienvenida y te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Para realizar preguntas es importante revises [ask] que te brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!, un gran saludo!.

Comment: SO es principalmente un sitio de programación. Echale un ojo a [ask]

Answer (score 2):

Sigue estos pasos a ver que tal te va:

1. Busca las siguientes carpetas y eliminalas:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodejs C:\Program Files\Nodejs
>   C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm (or %appdata%\npm)
>   C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache (or %appdata%\npm-cache)
>   C:\Users{User}.npmrc

2. Verifica las variables de entorno en tu %PATH% y elimina las referencias a Nodejs o npm si es que tienes alguna configurada.
3. Si haciendo esto no se ha des-instalado, en consola CMD escribe where node para verificar dónde está ubicado el archivo de node y elimina el directorio 
   (--delete) si no funciona así, ve hasta la ubicación y eliminalo manualmente.